# Collapsed sub-process with multiple end events (BPMN)

Tags: process, development-process, process-engineering

I am designing a [BPMN](http://www.bpmn.org/) business process and figured out that I do not understand, how subprocesses with multiple end events are managed. I'd like to mention that I am talking not about compensation events, which lead from collapsed subprocess, but about "normal" end events. Let say I have the following setup:

[image: Main process and processes 1 and 2]

[image: Example subprocess]

What I want here is that in case of default end-event was triggered Main process would continue to "Do other stuff" activity.

I have studied BPMN standard and lots of online articles, but I could not find examples of collapsed subprocesses with multiple end events.

I would be most grateful if somebody more experienced provided me with some info on whether this setup is correct or (in case not) how to do what I have described.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because despite the fact this work is the kind of thing often covered by a Project, it is not *actually* a Project Management question and is probably off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about project management.

Comment: I'm on the fence about this, as modeling a process is something that is part of good project management, but the question appears to be narrowly focused on some particular diagramming process which may be out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Event-based gateway can manage subprocesses with dynamic paths based on intermediate events:

> Event based gateways are a special case of deferred choice pattern where the process chooses a specific sequence and branch depending on the interaction with an external environment thereby allowing for true dynamicity. This is different from the exclusive gateway in the sense that it allows a branching point where alternative paths are determined based on intermediate events coming from external systems. The message flow waits at the event based gateway waiting for a token to arrive from any of its branches.

[image: Event-based gateway]

This allows for the main process to be initiated based on the multiple events:

> Whenever a cancellation event is received intermittently within a process an exclusive gateway decides whether a CustomerExperienceExecutive should make a personal call and deter the cancellation. If a resolution is reached i.e by means of changing the account type, account charges and privileges, the main process is re-initiated. Thus the process ends up having multiple start events, one that is for new applicants and one that is for re-applicants for whom the CheckCustomerSummary step may be skipped.

**References**

- [Controlling Process Flow Using Gateways](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/process-cloud/cprcw/controlling-process-flow-using-gateways.html#GUID-3431CBA9-56C0-4F38-9C8F-68867A096565)
- [Event Based Gateway Pattern | Oracle Technologies Primer](https://beatechnologies.wordpress.com/tag/event-based-gateway-pattern/)